# C - dynamic arrays

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I don't quite understand how pointers work with C arrays. Here's some code I got:

```
int arrayOne[] = {1, 2, 3};
int arrayTwo[] = {4, 5, 6, 7};

int **arrayThree = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
arrayThree[0] = arrayOne;
arrayThree[1] = arrayTwo;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    int *array = arrayThree[i];
    int length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        printf("arrayThree[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, array[j]);
}
```

I would have expected this to output the following:

```
arrayThree[0][0] = 1
arrayThree[0][1] = 2
arrayThree[0][2] = 3
arrayThree[1][0] = 4
arrayThree[1][1] = 5
arrayThree[1][2] = 6
arrayThree[1][3] = 7
```

What it actually prints out is:

```
arrayThree[0][0] = 1
arrayThree[0][1] = 2
arrayThree[1][0] = 4
arrayThree[1][1] = 5
```

Why?!

Comment: You don't need to typecast the void pointer result from malloc(), unless you are compiling C code on a C++ compiler, which is a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sizeof(array)` is the size of a pointer, which just happens to be the twice the size of an `int` on your platform.

There's no way to get the length of an array in C. You just have to remember it yourself.

Comment: @Erik My edit to correct that appeared a few seconds before your comment!!

Comment: "There's no way to get the length of an array in C. You just have to remember it yourself." Or use a special marker value, like the `\0` string terminator.

Comment: @David: Should be a badge for typing speed here :P

Comment: Then why does `int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; printf("sizeof(array) = %lu\n", sizeof(array) / sizeof(int));` work?

Comment: Because that's a constant sized array. That's the same as declaring it as `int array[7]`

Comment: Because you're using sizeof on an array, not on a pointer. Arrays can decay to pointers, but they're not the same thing.

Comment: @user @Michael's suggestion of terminating arrays with sentinels is the usual way of dealing with this issue. You iterate across the array until you reach the terminating sentinel. It only really works if you can reserve one special value.

Comment: So a constant array somehow stores its length, but a pointer (or an array that "decayed" to a pointer) doesn't?

Comment: @user282635: because the `sizeof` operator behaves differently for arrays and pointers.  In the original code, `array` is type `int *`, whereas in your comment it's type `int [7]`.

Comment: @user282635: it's not even "stored", it's computed at compilation time.

Comment: @user282635: no, the size of an array is part of its type, so the compiler knows without it being stored. This information is lost (to the compiler) when an array decays to a pointer. So when you do `int array[] = {1, 2, 3}`, the type of `array` is `int[3]`, so `sizeof array` is `3 * sizeof(int)`. When you do `int *array = whatever`, the type of `array` is just `int*`, no size information, and `sizeof array` is just `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: Steve's comment nails it. You *can* get the size of an array if you have a variable which type is the array. If all you have is a pointer to the beginning of the array than all you get is the size of the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `int **arrayThree = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int))` is wrong, it should be `sizeof(int *)`

Next, `sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)` corresponds to `sizeof(int *) / sizeof(int)` which is not what you want.

There is no "embedded" size information in a pointer that you treat as an array, you will need to manually manage the size.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no built-in mechanism** to keep track of the size of an array in C, you need to maintain it yourself, and pass it to any function that takes your array as parameter.

**However**, if you really need to use arrays extensively and in a dynamic manner in C, you can build your own library of dynamic arrays in C, without too much effort. For more information, refer to the following tutorial: goo.gl/vYhkF.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the allocation of `arrayThree` should be

```
int **arrayThree = malloc(2 * sizeof *arrayThree);
```

Since the type of `arrayThree` is `int **`, then the type of `*arrayThree` is `int *`.

The reason that `sizeof (array) / sizeof (int)` isn't returning what you expect is that `array` is a *pointer* (type `int *`), not an array type, so `sizeof` returns the number of bytes contained in the pointer *object* itself, not the number of elements pointed to.

There is no way to know from the pointer value alone how many elements are being pointed to; you must keep track of that information separately.